# Inner join a table using limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a 1-n relation between `collections` and `images` tables.

My goal is to select all collections given a condition together with the top 3 images of any collection found.

How I do it now:

Query on collections:

```
SELECT * FROM "collections" WHERE SOME_CONDITION
```

After selecting all collections, I run a query like this for each collection:

```
SELECT * FROM "images" WHERE "images"."collection_id" = MY_CURRENT_COLLECTION_ID LIMIT 3
```

My goal is to do it in one query:

```
SELECT "images".*
    ,"collections".*
FROM "collections"
INNER JOIN (SOME_MAGIC_TO_GET_THE_TOP_THREE_IMAGES_FOR_EACH_COLLECTION) AS "images" ON "images"."collection_id" = "collections"."id"
WHERE SOME_CONDITION
```

Any idea?

P.S. I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT img.*, 
       collections.*
FROM collections 
  JOIN (
    select *, 
           row_number() over (partition by collection_id order by something) as rn
    from images
  ) img ON img.collection_id = collections.id AND img.rn <= 3
WHERE ....;
```

Note that assigning a row_number() only works in a stable way if you can order the rows by something. The `something` in the statement above is any column in your `images` table that will enable you to properly sort those rows, e.g. the last modification date, or the creation date or something similar. You apparently need to replace `something` with an existing column.